# Regex delete spaces from every line start

Tags: regex, highlightjs

I use Highlight js plugin which auto indents my code.
My IDE also auto indents my code.

```
<div>
     <div>
         <pre>
              <code>
                   <h1>Hello world</h1>
              </code>
         </pre>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I would like to have this :

```
<h1>Hello word</h1>
```

But because Highlight js does not do relative indetation I end up with this :

```
                   <h1>Hello world</h1>
```

So I tried something like this

```
$('pre code').html($('pre code').html().replace(/^\s{24,}/g,''));
```

And it's working fine for the first line of the string but I would like to do this on every line -->
Remove every 24 first white spaces from every line start.

Comment: did you already tried these great online Regex helpers like: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yes I tried but my brain is regexproof :'(

Comment: `.replace(/^\s{24,}/gm,'')` or better: `.replace(/^[^\S\r\n]{24,}/gm,'')`. I counted 19 spaces in your sample only: [`/^[^\S\r\n]{19,}/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/wY5cB5/1)

Comment: What if you capture everything other than SPACE, and then replace the existing with the captured group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- `\s` matches newlines, too, so you need a `[^\S\r\n]` to match any *horizontal* space
- The `/m` modifier is required to make `^` match the beginning of a line, not of a whole string.

Since I counted only 19 spaces in your above sample, here is a working regex:

```
/^[^\S\r\n]{19,}/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY5cB5/1)